# Json_encode many data in PHP from database to Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been spending a day researching and trying to display a json_encoded multi-dimensional array from PHP to Jquery's AJAX until I tried fetching only 10 rows from 4200+ rows in my database's table. Is it impossible to send those thousands of rows to ajax as a json_encoded array? Or is there something wrong with my code or should there be something to consider and tweak? No hate please, just help.

cases.php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('connect-db.php');
$cases_sql = "SELECT * FROM cases ORDER BY case_id ASC LIMIT 10";
$cases_result = mysqli_query($conn, $cases_sql);

$cases_res = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cases_result)) {
    $cases_res[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($cases_res);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "cases.php",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
        alert(data[0].data.case_id);
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        alert("complete");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: A suggestion just fetch only those column which are needed.  second  improvement need to be inside while loop. also  in success you need to do something, just alert is there. Also if your server is strong enough then no problem in sending 4200+ record, but its not really good to send that much data using ajax in a single time frame

Comment: Under `url: "cases.php",` can you add `dataType: "json",`?

Comment: @madalinivascu I totally acidentially typed that and edited it before you made that post. I changed it to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in fact, but json_encode become really messy when you don't have characters in UTF-8.

```
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Try with something like this and tell us if it work.

Comment: IT WORKED. THANK YOU SOOO MUCH. Thank you.